# net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) nextjs adroll

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dangerouslysetinnerhtml, adroll

Hey I am trying to adroll to my nextjs app. But I keep receiving this error https://s.adroll.com/j/undefined/roundtrip.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden). This is the code i set in _app.js and index.js. Any ideas on what's going on, why is it blocked?

```
  <div className={styles.mainbackground}>
      <Script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
        
    adroll_adv_id = ${process.env.ADROLL_ID};
    adroll_pix_id = ${process.env.ADROLL_PIX_ID};
    adroll_version = "2.0";

    (function(w, d, e, o, a) {
        w.__adroll_loaded = true;
        w.adroll = w.adroll || [];
        w.adroll.f = [ 'setProperties', 'identify', 'track' ];
        var roundtripUrl = "https://s.adroll.com/j/" + adroll_adv_id
                + "/roundtrip.js";
        for (a = 0; a < w.adroll.f.length; a++) {
            w.adroll[w.adroll.f[a]] = w.adroll[w.adroll.f[a]] || (function(n) {
                return function() {
                    w.adroll.push([ n, arguments ])
                }
            })(w.adroll.f[a])
        }

        e = d.createElement('script');
        o = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        e.async = 1;
        e.src = roundtripUrl;
        o.parentNode.insertBefore(e, o);
    })(window, document);
    adroll.track("pageView");
`,
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Do you have an ad blocker installed in your browser? If so, try disabling it.

Comment: Disable it completely or just for the site ? I tried both and nothing changed.

Comment: The URL with an error has `undefined` in the path. Make sure that your code is properly setting the `adroll_adv_id` and `adroll_pix_id` variables. Looks like it's trying to populate from environment variables.

Comment: yes, but not sure why.Is there a way to fix this?